# Why window names are appearing in brackets? How I can remove them?

Tags: lubuntu, window, panel, taskbar

[image]

This is the image of the Taskbar from my Lubuntu. Why the name of every window appears in a bracket? How can I remove it?

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The brackets indicate minimized windows. Non-minimized windows have no brackets.